# Use pseudo-element to overlay a scrolling div

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I would like to cover a div with dynamic scrolling content with a pseudo element overlay.
The issue I have encountered is the overlay scrolls with the content, leaving any content below the fold naked.

How can I allow the overlay to remain in place as the content below it scrolls?

```css
.wantOverlay {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.wantOverlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
}
```

```html
<div class="wantOverlay">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Unfortunately any text past this point no longer has the overlay.</div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl.dr. Change `after` for `before`, remove `top` and `left` properties and inherit `width` and `height` and change `position` to `fixed`.

Explanation after example.

```css
.wantOverlay {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.wantOverlay::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
}
```

```html
<div class="wantOverlay">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Unfortunately any text past this point no longer has the overlay.</div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
</div>
```

So, what is happening here:
You want a fixed behavior so we change position to `fixed`. This comes with the drawback that the other properties will be set using the window as a base not the parent element. So we fix it, to set the position as the same of your div we remove `top` and `left` properties and change the `after` for `before`. To make it the same size we use `inherit` since `100%` would be `100%` of the window.

**EDIT**

Caveat: I wrote this as a self dare to find a way to use fixed position. I actually don't think this is the best answer since it will only work if there is no scroll in the whole page. If this happens the gray square will be always in the same place of the window while the content would move up and down.

If I were to do this for a client's site I think I would create a parent div with two children, the content and the overlay. If you want to keep scroll functional you can use the css property `pointer-events:none;` on the overlay.

Comment: Although this works, inheriting the width also covers the scrollbar. The ui side of me wants to shy away from that because a grayed out scrollbar can show non-intractability.

Comment: This is the only response so far that works completely for text of varying length.  For future web travelers, you can use `calc()` to subtract the size of the scrollbar to prevent the overlay from covering it.

Answer (score 7):

`position: sticky;` with negative `margin-top` will do the trick. Here is details about `sticky` https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/CSS/position

```css
.wantOverlay {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.wantOverlay::after {
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
}
```

```html
<div class="wantOverlay">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Unfortunately any text past this point no longer has the overlay.</div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: After some testing, this has a similar problem as Syden's answer if the length of text changes.

Comment: It's worth noting that position: sticky is a pretty new feature and may not support enough browsers for you. http://www.caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Comment: @Enigmadan Yes you are right, tested this with more text and it didn't work. Will try to find a better way. If I can, will edit this one... Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Scoots For my purposes, multiple browser support is unimportant, but this is important for others to note if they stumble across this question.

Comment: `sticky` is the solution! It’s another fruitful blend of formerly hacky properties, but it’s still not yet properly memorized …

Answer (score 1):

You can use a huge `box-shadow` spread value, with the background that you want, for example:

```
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
```

This will cover everything, but since `box-shadow` can't effect the layout, it won't increase the scroll height.

**Note: this is a hack that might effect performance, so use with caution.**

```css
.wantOverlay {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.wantOverlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
}
```

```html
<div class="wantOverlay">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Unfortunately any text past this point no longer has the overlay.</div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Unfortunately any text past this point no longer has the overlay.</div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate that this solves the specific issue, but it seems a bit too hacky to put into production. (Especially when there are other methods.) I wonder how many pixels of box-shadow you need to crash a browser...

Comment: I'm not sure how it effects the browser when most of it is not rendered. Personally I would go with the position sticky answer. The only problem is browser support.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT based on comment:**

You can position it fixed with the unfolded content dimensions. Text could be dynamic.

```css
.wantOverlay {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.wantOverlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wantOverlay">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id. </div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
</div>
```

Less text:

```css
.wantOverlay {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.wantOverlay::after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(150, 150, 150, .45);
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wantOverlay">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed est vel ante faucibus tempor nec id.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  <div>This text no longer has the overlay.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for my case as the text in my div will be dynamic.  I'm not sure how much text there will be, and so hardcoding the extra length isn't something I can do.  If this were another situation where I knew the text would be constant, this would work nicely.  Calc is cool!

Comment: @Enigmadan sorry for the late reply, I edited above, should work with dynamic text now.