# Background image in the pseudo-element covering scrollable content

Tags: css, sass, background-image, pseudo-element

Consider:

```
    @mixin pseudo-element-background {
        content: ""; 
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: top;
        // background-attachment: fixed; // distorts the image
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    
    div {
        position: relative;
        width: 20rem;
        max-height: 10rem;
        overflow-y: auto;
        
        &::before {
            background-image: url(http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/18380-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg);
          
            @include pseudo-element-background;
        }
    }
```

```
    <div>
    <h1>Text1</h1>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
    <h1>Text3</h1>
    <h1>Text4</h1>
    <h1>Text5</h1>
    <h1>Text6</h1>
    <h1>Text7</h1>
    <h1>Text8</h1>
    <h1>Text9</h1>
    <h1>Text10</h1>
    </div>
```

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/bGobwbE?editors=1100).

When one scrolls, he discovers white background, whereas I would like the background image to cover the whole content. Note that the background image has to be in the pseudo-element. I tried ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624147/use-pseudo-element-to-overlay-a-scrolling-div) to no avail. I could also put a negative value for `bottom` in the mixin, but I do not know what value to put so it would cover the whole content. So, how do I achieve this?

In addition, I would like to fix the background position, but uncommenting the line `background-attachment: fixed;` distorts the background. I would like to understand why this happens and how to fix it.

Comment: Not all browsers support background-attachment: fixed fully - see https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the pseudo element absolute is that it scrolls with the content.

Try putting the background direct on the element instead.

UPDATE: there is a requirement to also have a linear-gradient over the background image. This snippet has one added as a demo:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 20rem;
  max-height: 10rem;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5)), url(http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/18380-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Text1</h1>
  <h1>Text2</h1>
  <h1>Text3</h1>
  <h1>Text4</h1>
  <h1>Text5</h1>
  <h1>Text6</h1>
  <h1>Text7</h1>
  <h1>Text8</h1>
  <h1>Text9</h1>
  <h1>Text10</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: The question states: "Note that the background image has to be in the pseudo-element." The reason is that I am overlaying another gradient background onto this one. So, even if I put this one into the element, I will have the same problem with the gradient.

Comment: Can’t the gradient be in the same background-image statement as the image one?

Comment: I think I tried, but could not make it work. Both are linear gradients, one with an image url.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.ostack.cn/?qa=759092/) post and here is a working solution based on it:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  &>div{
    position: relative;
    &:before {
      content: "";
      z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-image: url(http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/18380-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg);
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>Text1</h1>
    <h1>Text2</h1>
    <h1>Text3</h1>
    <h1>Text4</h1>
    <h1>Text5</h1>
    <h1>Text6</h1>
    <h1>Text7</h1>
    <h1>Text8</h1>
    <h1>Text9</h1>
    <h1>Text10</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/RwLbjVB?editors=1100).

I think the idea is to add a parent and make the scrolling belong to the parent, so that now the whole scrollable content of the child is part of the child's height. This makes it possible to use `height:100%` in the pseudo-element.